# Importing SVG with Snap.svg doesn't display gradients

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to use Snap.svg to import an existing SVG using the Snap.svg `load` function.  It works, however, any gradients that are in the original SVG file are removed and their areas are simply filled white.  Is this expected behavior, or am I missing something?

Note - SVG was created in Inkscape. Displays correctly if using `<embed>` or `<object>`.

When I use `<embed src="robot.svg"/>`, it displays properly, like so
http://postimg.org/image/pwe9zute3/

However, when I use

```
<script>
  var s = Snap("24in","12in");
  Snap.load("robot.svg", function (f) {
      var g = f.select("g");
      s.append(g);
  });          
</script>
```

it loads like this
http://postimg.org/image/5u0woiw7n/

Below is a link to download the SVG if anyone wants to inspect it.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bdtujg1vr2dp6f4/robot.svg?dl=0

Interesting note - When displaying as a preview on the dropbox site, it also has no gradient.  However, downloading the SVG from Dropbox and viewing it in a browser, it has the gradient.

Comment: Can you attach a testcase to the question please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't appending the gradient definitions into snap, just the contents of the `<g>` elements in the drawing and the gradients are under a `<defs>` element.